# Sending nServiceBus messages with FitNesse

Tags: c#, nservicebus, fitnesse

I am having trouble connecting my FitNesse test to my c# project that uses `nServiceBus` to send messages to the MSMQ.

```
__EXCEPTION__:System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. 
---> System.InvalidOperationException: No configuration file found at: .\FitNesse\slim\Runner.exe.config, 
the default configuration for nservicebus requires an app.config to be present. Please add one!
```

I have tried pointing the wiki page to the `app.config` and the `app.dll.config` with using the flag `-a` but both have turned up to be unsuccessful.

Comment: Please move your comment to an answer and then accept it.  This will help people more readily see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I copied over all of the third party dll's to that folder that contains Runner.exe and copied over my app.config and renamed it to Runner.exe. Everything worked, hope this helps someone else.